Show $u(x) \le K$... (inequality using ODE)
I am studying ODE prelim exams and came across this question,

Assume that the function $u(x) \ge 0$ is of class $C[1,\infty)$, and
\begin{equation} xu(x) \le K + \int_1^x u(t) dt \text{ for } x \ge 1. \end{equation}
Show that $u(x)\le K$ for $x \ge 1$.

I am quite stumped by the fact that we cannot assume $u(x)$ is differentiable. My idea was to rewrite the problem as follows,

Let $f(x) := \int_1^x u(t) dt$, then we have,
\begin{align} x f'(x) &\le K + f(x). \end{align}

However, I do not know where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

I think you are on the right track. It looks very similar to a Gronwall-type inequality, but you can solve it the way you were proceeding. Just re-write
$$ xf'(x) - f(x) \leq K $$
and then do an integrating factor. In this case, multiplying each side by $1/x^2$ gives
$$\frac 1 {x} f'(x) -  \frac 1 {x^2} f(x) \leq K/x^2.$$ Then integrating both sides and rearranging terms gives $f(x) \leq K(x-1)$. From here, you can get the more general inequality $\int_y^x u(t) \, \mathrm d t \leq K(x-y)$ from which the final result follows.

Nice answer! I did not expect this to have such an ODE-flavoured solution.

@SeverinSchraven Thanks! Your answer was very nice as well.

Or just restart with the original inequality, $xu(x)\le K+f(x)\le K+(x-1)K$,...

My main intuition comes from pretending that $u$ is monotone. In that case the inequality becomes
$$xu(x)\leq K + (x-1)u(x)$$
which readily implies $u(x)\leq K$. Now really the only thing needed for this to work is $u(x)=\sup_{[1,x]} u$. This will allow us to prove the inequality via contradiction.
Assume that there exists $x_0>1$ such that $u(x_0)>K$. Then pick $x_1\in [1, x_0]$ such that
$$u(x_1)=\sup_{x\in [1,x_0]} u(x).$$
In particular we have
$$u(x_1)=\sup_{x\in [1, x_1]} u(x)>K.$$
Then using the inequality
\begin{align*}
x_1 u(x_1)&\leq K + \int_1^{x_1} u(x)dx \\
&\leq K + (x_1-1)\sup_{x\in [1,x_1]} u(x) \\
&< x_1 u(x_1)
\end{align*}
we get a contradiction.
